# How to unpickle and fit machine learning using right sklearn version

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Here's my code

```
import joblib
lgbm_v4 = joblib.load('lgbm_v4.pkl')
```

The User Warning

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:315: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LabelEncoder from version 0.24.1 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
```

Here's error message when I try `result = lgbm_v4.score(X_test, y_test)`

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

TypeError: Labels in y_true and y_pred should be of the same type. Got y_true=['0' '1'] and y_pred=[0 1]. Make sure that the predictions provided by the classifier coincides with the true labels.

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

TypeError: attrib() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert'
```

What I suppose to do, I think it is basic code, why the error is so complex

Comment: What is `y_test.dtype`?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Comment: The warning suggests that these are consequences of version mismatches. Use a consistent version throughout your project/pipeline

Comment: @NabihBawazir What are the names and dtypes of column(s) in `y_test`? There should only have one column, and its dtype should be numeric (e.g., float64), not string (object)

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler `Index(['flag_bad'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @NabihBawazir Thanks! Try converting `y_test` into a numpy array of floats before calling `.score`: `y_test = y_test['flag_bad'].astype(float)`

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler The UserWarning no longer show up and the error is much more familiar, thanks